# Flurry analytics doesn't seem to log events in ios 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, analytics, flurry

In the past days I'm having issues with flurry api, and it seems that it 
stopped working.

My build ios version is 4.2 and the Flurry version is Flurry iPhone SDK v4.0.4

In my code I'm doing this:

```
[Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];

[Flurry startSession:@"MY_API_KEY"];

[Flurry logEvent:@"Entered app"];
```

And I'm getting:

```
Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: Flurry: startSession 
called for the first time

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: Flurry: Start session 
called with apiKey[MY_API_KEY]

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: Flurry: Trim white space 
and use apiKey[MY_API_KEY]

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: initial network status [1] 
=========

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: FlurrySession: Add session 
with startTime[2012-10-11 19:36:13 +0000] to saved sessions

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Error>: -[__NSCFNumber length]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4504a0

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: Flurry: Finish starting 
session with apiKey[MY_API_KEY]

Oct 12 18:17:40 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: FlurrySession: dealloc 
session
```

And no event Entered app seems to be logged or viewed in debug, except:

```
Oct 12 18:23:11 unknown myApp[2981] <Warning>: Flurry: setGender[M]

Oct 12 18:25:03 unknown myApp[3001] <Warning>: Flurry: setUserID[5]
```

Also if running it in xcode it stopped in this line

```
[Flurry startSession:@"MY_API_KEY"];
```

And only after pressing twice the continue program execution the program 
continues to run.

In the iphone (without the xcode) it runs smoothly but the debug log is the 
same, and no events seems to be logged.

Any suggestions?

p.s. Tried to talk to flurry support about this, no one got back to me for 3 days now...

Comment: More than a month dropping a mail to Flurry support. No one got back. Disappointing. Huge turn off and decided to integrate Google Analytics in the end. smh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `[Flurry setUserID:currUserId]` when currUserId was `NSNumber* (due to passing of id currUserId),` caused the problem.
Always make sure that you pass the  value `NSString* to Flurry`, also in events values....

Answer (score 2):

Good to see that the issue got resolved. It seems that for some reason your mail did not reach Flurry. For any further issues, please feel free to write to support@flurry.com. We'll make sure your query is answered within 24 hours. (Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Answer (score 0):

If we use flurry event in background,we should enable 
[Flurry setBackgroundSessionEnabled:YES]; under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in Appdelegate.
    To enable background session the error of [_NSCF Number length] is avoided,it can able to track the event.